# Protractor, element not displayed or not present?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

Is there a way to test if an element is not present or not displayed ?

I have some elements that on some pages are not present and some other pages are just not displayed. How can i test this with only one instruction ?

Actually if i put :
`expect(element.isDisplayed()).toBe(false)`
it's ok when not displayed but crashes when not present.
And 
`expect(element.isPresent()).toBe(false)`
it's ok when not present but crashes when present but not displayed...

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own method.

```
public shouldBeVisible(elem: ElementFinder, shouldBe: boolean) {
    if (!shouldBe) {
        return elem.isPresent().then((isPres) => {
            if (!isPres) {
                return expect(elem.isPresent()).toBe(false);
            }
            return expect(elem.isDisplayed()).toBe(false);
        });
    }
    return expect(elem.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
}
```

Comment: So you suggest that there is no built-in method to do that ?

Comment: AFAIK there's no built-in solution.

Comment: Ok didn't find too, I guess you're true. Many thanks !